# Ubuntu LTS performance is good but sometimes slow

Tags: 12.04, performance

Ubuntu Unity is fast in my computer running multiple windows etc., but after an update, Software Center suddenly shows and when a script stops running (usually when I'm on FB), it suddenly slows down and sometimes freezes.

*How do I prevent the script to suddenly stop?

How do I choose a tag, its so difficult to put one?*

Comment: Did you try turning off Automatic Updates?

Comment: Updating sometimes noticeably affects your disk i/o but I wonder if your symptoms are caused by Flash running on Facebook pages? If this is correct try Chrome, it has the least bad Flash support in Linux.

Comment: how do i turn off automatic updates?

Answer (score 2):

Usually when the update program is running it will download all the new sources and process them which takes a bit of processing power to do, and then if you click update it will run through each one and install them...  It's only natural that things may slow down during this process...

Answer (score 1):

If this is caused by I/O waits because of lots of dirty pages being written out to disk, you may like to try a different I/O scheduler to see if this helps.  Try the "deadline" I/O scheduler and see if it makes a difference, for example for block device /dev/sda, use:

```
 echo "deadline" | sudo tee  /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```